# How to exclude a range from another range in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, range

Suppose I've a range (section) and an additional list of ranges to exclude, represented by tuples (start, end):

```
section=(1, 100) #Range from 1 to 100

toexclude=[(10,15),(40,50),(80,83)]  #3 sub-ranges
```

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm which returns, from these two inputs, a new list of ranges like:

```
[(1,9),(16,39),(51,79),(84,100)]
```

Which is the main range exluding the second list of ranges.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Actually the advice from deceze to use intervaltree seems to be interesting. With a few lines:

```
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree
t=IntervalTree()
t[1:100]="main"
t.chop(10,15)
t.chop(40,50)
t.chop(80,83)
t
IntervalTree([Interval(1, 10, 'main'), Interval(15, 40, 'main'), Interval(50, 80, 'main'), Interval(83, 100, 'main')])
```

The intervals are considered closed apparently, but this is a minor issue.

Comment: Write something inefficient first, and then improve it.

Comment: Are the sub-ranges guaranteed to be non-overlapping, or not?

Comment: Yes the sub-ranges are guaranteed to be non-overlapping.

Comment: Depending on how dynamic this needs to be and how you want to query this, an [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) may be appropriate.

Comment: Are the ranges guaranteed to be ordered (i.e the first contains smaller values than the second)?

Comment: Are the subranges guaranteed to be inside the first range?

Comment: It appears that you want your "ranges" to include only integers, which does agree with Python's ranges. However, it also appears that your "ranges" include both the endpoints, which is not pythonic. Python's ranges include the lower stated value but not the upper one. Is my understanding of what you want correct, and do you not want to change it to be more pythonic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner does not show any code or algorithm of his/her own.

Comment: If the IntervalTree works as intended, you should add it in an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like this?

```
start, end = section

this_start = start
result = []
for exc_start, exc_end in toexclude:
    this_end = exc_start - 1
    result.append((this_start, this_end))
    this_start = exc_end + 1

result.append((this_start, end))
```

**EDIT:** added `if` clause to correct according to Paco H. comment

```
start, end = section

this_start = start
result = []
for exc_start, exc_end in toexclude:
    if this_end == start:
        start = exc_end + 1
    else:
        this_end = exc_start - 1
        result.append((this_start, this_end))
        this_start = exc_end + 1

if this_end <= end:
    result.append((this_start, end))
```

Comment: Input: `section = (1, 100); toexclude = [(1, 10), (90, 100)]`. Output: `[(1, 0), (11, 89), (101, 100)]`. It works with the author's example, but not with this input, for example.

Comment: that's right, but I thought the author specified not overlapping sub-ranges... anyway i'm sure it can be done better, I will try to edit it soon!

Comment: also, it is not clear from the question what the output should be in case `toexclude = [(2, 10)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
section=(1, 100) #Range from 1 to 100

toexclude=[(10,15),(40,50),(80,83)]  #3 sub-ranges


rangelists = [x for excRange in toexclude for x in range(excRange[0], excRange[1] + 1)]
first, last = section[0], section[0]
out_ranges = []
for x in range(section[0],section[1] + 1):
    if x not in rangelists:
        if first == 'unset':
            first = x
        last = x
    elif x in rangelists:
        if last == x - 1:
            out_ranges.append((first, last))
            first = 'unset'
        else:
            continue
if first != 'unset':
    out_ranges.append((first, last))

print out_ranges
```

Answer (score 0):

```
section=(1, 100) #Range from 1 to 100

toexclude=[(10,15),(40,50),(80,83)]  #3 sub-rang

list1 = []
list2 = [section[0]]
[list1.append(x[0]-1) for x in toexclude]
[list2.append(x[1]+1) for x in toexclude]
list1.append(section[1])

print list(zip(list2, list1)
# [(1, 9), (16, 39), (51, 79), (84, 100)]
```